# WebKit release and dependencies

Tags: development, kernel-modules

I am using WebKit for navigating web pages and rendering UI in my application.
I wanted to know the dependencies of WebKit with new kernel modules.

- How to find out that the particular version of WebKit will work with all kernel versions?
- How to come to know about the new releases of WebKit and the kernel modules supported by this version?

Answer (score 2):

In general high presentation libraries (like lib webkit) do not interface directly with the kernel, which means they don't depend on any specific kernel version. Instead such libraries depend on specific versions of a set of other libraries.

Newer versions of webkit might depend on newer versions of those libraries, the required versions are usually documented on the source.